# Angular 8 - Multiple HTTP calls in a for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There is a list of unlimited cars in backend.
Each car has an id (unique id) and a name (car model name).

I have the list of car IDs, example:

```js
const carIds = ['abc','xyz'];
```

and I need to fetch respective car names for the above car Ids.
I tried the below code, but its not working at all, what is that I'm missing ?

```js
const carIds = ['abc','xyz']; // unique ids
const carsList = [];
for (const carId of carIds) {
  this.api.getCar(carId).pipe(
    map(response => {
      carsList.push({
        name: response.name,
        id: carId
      });
    })
  );
}
console.log(carsList); // When I run this, its printing nothing.
```

Expected Output:

```js
carsList = [{
 id: 'abc',
 name: 'benz'
},{
 id: 'xyz',
 name: 'mercede'
}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Promise.all([ promise1, promise2 ])` to run 2 promises at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to subscribe to many streams by once and get the result when all stream are complete, it is like a promise.all for rxjs.

```js
const carIds = ['abc','xyz']; // unique ids
const httpCalls = carIds.map(id => this.api.getCar(id)) // array of streams
const carsList$ = forkJoin(httpCalls).pipe(
   map(results => results.map((r, index) => ({ id: carIds[index], name: r.name }));
);

carsList$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const carsList = [];

for await (const carId of carIds) {
  const car = await this.api.getCar(carId);
  car && carsList.push({
        name: car.name,
        id: carId
      });
}
```

Try this code. Happy to help :)